# Is it possible to prompt users to update their Phone number on Login, using Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I know via AD it is possible to get a used to update their password on next log in.

Is it possible to do the same thing to the other fields of a user?

Eg prompt them to update their phone number, and address?
By displaying some kind of dialog.

Is this simple, or would I have to build something from scratch, then deploy it via group policy.

Comment: `Is it possible to do the same thing to the other fields of a user?` - Not natively. Furthermore, users don't have permissions to write to user account attributes (although they can change their own password)

Comment: As long as you have this info a spreadsheet, database, etc, its probably easier to implement a bulk account update with a privileged service account.

Comment: The key point is to *gain* this information.

Answer (score 2):

I seen a project like that for a school, but we fall into a programming project.

It's done in two step.

1 - You need to create a executable/script that will deleguate control over all users account over their own account to read/write the address and phone number. An example there for deleguating control in the GUI, https://dani3lr.wordpress.com/2009/07/25/delegation-control-to-modify-only-certain-user-attributes-part-1/.

2 - You need to create an application to allow the user to change their own detail. System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement could maybe be used in dotnet 3.5. An example there of the usage; http://muraliimohanb.blogspot.ca/2010/05/managing-directory-security-principals.html

It's the big step only, but it can help to give you a path.